# Ajax is not working inside Featherlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, featherlight.js

I am trying to add ajax photo uploading script inside a Featherlight lightbox but it's not working!
So if anyone could please let me know what I am doing wrong, that'd be great! I am already adding JQuery library; everything else is working fine but ajax is not submitting the uploaded photo when the uploading form is kept in lightbox div in order to load it in a lightbox!
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('#uploadForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data:formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data)
        {
      $("#targetLayer").html(data);
        },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }));

    $(".inputFile").on("change", function() {
        $("#uploadForm").submit();
    });
});
</script>

<a href="#" data-featherlight="#add_new_profile" data-featherlight-variant="fixwidth"><button class="btn btn-success">Add New Client Profile</button></a>
  <div class="lightbox" id="add_new_profile">

      <div class="bgColor">
<form id="uploadForm" action="upload_image.php" method="post">
<div id="targetLayer">No Image</div>
<div id="uploadFormLayer">
<label>Upload Image File:</label><br/>
<input name="userImage" id="userImage" type="file" class="inputFile" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
</div>

  <form id="contact" action="actions.php" method="post">
    <h3>Add New Profile</h3>
    <h4>Fill All Require Details In Order To Add A Client Profile!</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Namn (Name)" name="full_name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Ålder (Age)" name="age" type="text" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Ort (City)" name="city" type="text" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Yrke (Profession)" name="profession" type="text" tabindex="4" required>
    </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Kundnr (Client ID)" name="client_id" type="text" tabindex="5" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Info" tabindex="6" name="info" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" value="create" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form> 
       </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: If anyone can please point out the issue to me...Will be great..!

Comment: Could you make a simplified live example in jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure...let me give you access to my live project...Where I have this issue :

Comment: Login in there and then open clients management tab page and there will be a button as "Add New Profile" where I have put the php ajax image uploading form in that lightbox and it doesn't work..!

Comment: Site Link : http://huntedhunter.com/drag_gallery/

Comment: Login Access Details : 
Username : Admin
Password : umair1111

Comment: More like the the ajax upload form doesn't work but when I click submit button manually then it works and submit form and the image is uploaded but doesn't show in there which is also related to ajax success triggers and get back html from php upload but it doesn't put that success in there..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using IDs in your lightbox. Featherlight duplicates the DOM objects, be default (unless you use the `persist` option). Use classes instead of IDs, use a better locator than `$("#targetLayer")` and you'll be ok.

Comment: Thanks...it wasn't really that sort of problem..But it was JQuery problem..I changed JQuery to load in the head of the file while it was before in footer..!